# Scraping table data from multiple links and combine this together in one excel file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a link, and within that link, I have some products. Within each of these products, there is a table of specifications. The table is such that first column should be the header, and second column the data corresponding to it. The first column for each of these tables is different, with some overlapping categories. I want to get one big table that has all these categories, and in rows, the different products. I am able to get data for one table (one product) as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import csv
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= "https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-airfit-n30-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear"
source_code= requests.get(url)
plain_text= source_code.text
soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
table= soup.find("table", {"class":"table"})

print(table)
output_rows=[]
table_rows= table.find_all('tr')
#print(table_rows)

headers = [td.text for td in soup.select_one('.table').select('td:nth-of-type(1)')]
with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(headers)
    for table in soup.select('table'):
        w.writerow([td.text for td in table.select('td:nth-of-type(2)')])
```

I understand for different products I will have to loop over the link to eac product, and I am able to do that. However, how do I append each table to the previous output such that the required table structure is maintained?

Comment: Append all your results to a list i.e. make a list of list and then call `pd.DataFrame(data=my_data, headers=[col_names])`

Comment: I tried writing this and now I get all the tables appended, however how do I filter unique values so only unique headers appear in the first row, and the products are attributed serial number wise in these categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.1800cpap.com/cpap-masks/nasal'

def get_item(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    print('Getting {}..'.format(url))

    title = soup.select_one('h1.product-details-full-content-header-title').get_text(strip=True)

    all_data = {'Item Title': title}
    for tr in soup.select('#product-specs-list tr'):
        h, v = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
        all_data[h.rstrip(':')] = v

    return all_data

all_data = []
for page in range(1, 2):
    print('Page {}...'.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params={'page': page}).content, 'html.parser')

    for a in soup.select('a.facets-item-cell-grid-title'):
        u = 'https://www.1800cpap.com' + a['href']
        all_data.append(get_item(u))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Prints:

```
Page 1...
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-airfit-n30-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/dreamwear-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear-by-philips-respironics..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/eson-2-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear-by-fisher-and-paykel..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-mirage-fx-nasal-cpap-mask..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/airfit-n30i-nasal-cpap-mask-by-resmed..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/dreamwisp-nasal-cpap-mask-fitpack..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/respironics-comfortgel-blue-cpap-nasal-mask-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-mirage-fx-for-her-nasal-cpap-mask..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/airfit-n20-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/wisp-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/pico-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear-by-philips-respironics-2..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/airfit-n20-for-her-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/airfit-f10-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/fisher-and-paykel-zest-q-nasal-mask-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-swift-fx-nano-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-ultra-mirage-2-nasal-cpap-mask..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/airfit-n10-for-her-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/eson-nasal-cpap-mask-by-fisher-and-paykel..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-swift-fx-nano-nasal-cpap-mask-for-her-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/mirage-activa-lt-cpap-mask-by-resmed..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-mirage-micro-cpap-mask..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/phillips-respironics-trueblue-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/fisher-paykel-zest-cpap-mask..
Getting https://www.1800cpap.com/viva-nasal-cpap-mask-by-3b-medical..
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]